# why can't vagrant/puppet find apache?

Tags: provisioning, vagrant, puppet

Here's the output on running `vagrant up`. Besides this, I'm not even sure what information will be helpful.

puppetlabs-apache is available in subdir: modules

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

```
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
[default] Fixed port collision for 80 => 8080. Now on port 2201.
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 80 => 2201 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
[default] Running provisioner: puppet...
Running Puppet with default.pp...
stdin: is not a tty
warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
warning: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: precise32
Could not find class apache for precise32 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:5     on node precise32
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cd /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests && puppet apply --verbose --debug --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' default.pp --detailed-exitcodes || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

Comment: the folder /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0 is created on the VM. So perhaps it's a permissions issue? If so, how could I set the permissions on a folder transferred from the host via vagrant/puppet?

Comment: These files and folders are world readable, so not an issue, I think.

Comment: Do you actually have the apache module in the modules folder? Also you should set the hostname of your box to stop the fqdn error

Comment: Vagrant sets the puppet modules = "puppet/modules"
within /puppet/modules exists /puppetlabs-apache that itself contains all the files from that repo.

Comment: I suggest you the following to improve the question: post the content of your `Vagrantfile` and add to the Puppet provisioning block the line: `puppet.options = "--debug --verbose"`, so you can see Puppet detailed output.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the name of the folder from puppetlabs-apache to just apache. The module name must match the folder name.